# Javascript console.log strings printing each character of an array on single lines

Tags: javascript

When I try to console.log strings in an array it prints each text character and the comma separators on a separate line:

```
var name = ["add","bas","cun","deh"];
var size = [2,5,7,9];
var price = [250,150,25,60];
var count = 0;
var mVar = 4;
var nameLen = name.length;

while (count < mVar) {

    var maxSize = Math.max.apply(null, size);
    var posVar = size.indexOf(maxSize);
    console.log(name[posVar] + " " + size[posVar] + " " + price[posVar]);
    size[posVar] = null
    count++;
}
```

When I view the console, these are my results:

[image: results]

Comment: Remove the vars (declarations) from inside the loop, just leave the assignments

Comment: Well, what exactly are you trying to get? Do you not want it on a separate line? Do you not want the comma separators? Having your objective would allow us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got bitten by global [window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). Change your variable to something else or get it out of the global scope.

Comment: Thanks! output is working perfectly putting the full strings with spacing.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is a reserved javascript word.

```
var names = ["add","bas","cun","deh"];
var sizes = [2,5,7,9];
var prices = [250,150,25,60];

console.log(names.map((n, i) => [n, sizes[i], prices[i]].join(' ')).join('\n'));
```